# Unzip a Windows Archive on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server

I zipped archive on Windows but I cannot unzip it on Ubuntu I tried 7z (tar) I tried .7z but everytime I get error.

I tried `sudo apt-get install unzip` but I get this error everytime:

```
root@ip-172-31-31-126:/var/www# unzip wiki.zip
Archive:  wiki.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of wiki.zip or
        wiki.zip.zip, and cannot find wiki.zip.ZIP, period.
```

Comment: Assuming the archive is not corrupted, probably `unzip` does not like some of your compression settings. I recommend using the 7z format instead of ZIP.

Comment: How exactly did you zip your windows files!
Unzipping those files require the same flags and other options !
Fx: Did you chose to use a password or encryption??!
Any special options selected??!
and so forth...

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely going to need to install a couple of things. Open a terminal and type in these commands.

```
apt-get install zip

apt-get install unzip
```

Instructions for using them can be found at [THIS LINK](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-can-i-zipping-and-unzipping-files-under-linux.html) It's pretty simple and straight forward.

Comment: I already have that however when I try unzip it gives me this error:
root@ip-172-31-31-126:/var/www# unzip wiki.zip
Archive:  wiki.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of wiki.zip or
        wiki.zip.zip, and cannot find wiki.zip.ZIP, period

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the 7zip package on Ubuntu Server 
For that Open a terminal
run following command 
$ sudo apt-get install p7zip-full

To unzip the 7z zip file

run following command

$ 7z x example.7z

(example.7z is the zip file name).

Thanks